# Android save file in internal memory not working properly

Tags: android, listview, save

I'm trying to save the elements of a list (added by the user via a dialog box) into a file so that it stays the same when reopened. For some reason it throws a nullPointerException when I add elements to it the second time (first time works nicely). This is how I save:

```
public void onPause(){
        super.onPause();
        try {
            OutputStreamWriter out = new OutputStreamWriter(openFileOutput(salvare, 0));
            for(int i=0; i<lista.orase.size(); i++){
                out.write(lista.getItem(i)+"\n"); //ia fiecare element al listei si il scrie in fisier urmat de endline;
            }
            out.close();
            System.out.println("ON PAUSE!");
        } catch (Throwable t){

        }
    }
```

And this is how I retrieve onCreate:

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        lista=new ListaOrase(this);
        buton=(Button)findViewById(R.id.buton);

        setListAdapter(lista);

        try {
            InputStream in= openFileInput(salvare);
            if(in!=null){
                InputStreamReader tmp = new InputStreamReader(in);
                BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(tmp);
                String str;
                while(reader.readLine()!=null){
                    str=reader.readLine();
                    lista.add(str);
                        }
                in.close();
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
```

The exception is thrown by this function (which worked beautifully before adding the save feature). It gets the intent from the dialog box and adds the element to the list.

```
public void onActivityResult (int requestCode, int responseCode, Intent data){
                if(responseCode==1){
            String s=data.getStringExtra("oras");   
            lista.add(s);
            setListAdapter(lista);
        }
    }
```

What could possibly be the connection between them and how could I fix it?

Comment: In the onCreate method, you need to put setListAdapter(lista); after you fill lista with the str from the file. One more thing need to notice is that in the method onActivityResult, check s is null or not before adding to lista.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was that I wasn't "refreshing" my ListAdapter. Along with notifyDataSetChanged() I readded setListAdapter(lista) as Chunhui suggested.